# problem with json data(Arabic characters) that encoded with utf8_encode of PHP in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to send json data(Arabic characters) that encoded  with utf8_encode of PHP:

```
<?php
  $output = utf8_encode('مثال');/*Arabic characters*/
  echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

in javascript file of page :

```
.
.
.
const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
const div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
div1.textContent = response ;/*show ÙØ«Ø§Ù*/
.
.
.
```

why response value is 'ÙØ«Ø§Ù'?

Comment: Please try with `$output = 'مثال';  echo ($output);` as php code

Comment: in php  I've used <meta charset="utf-8" /> and only the first page of php  is displayed correctly

Comment: `utf8_encode()` converts from ISO8859-1 to UTF8, and Arabic is definitvely _not_ 8859-1 [Western European codepage]. I'm willing to bet that it's already UTF8 and you should not do anything to it.